# How to get Wifi AP details like SSID, Band, etc when connected in Android API level 28 and above?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I am trying to get Wifi AP details. I am using the following code

```
    private val TAG = "[MainActivity]"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                if(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION == intent?.action){
                    val networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra<NetworkInfo>(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO)
                    if(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI == networkInfo.type){
                        val wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
                        val info = wifiManager.connectionInfo
                        Log.d(TAG, "info = $info")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)
        applicationContext.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter)
    }
```

NetworkInfo and ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI are shown to be deprecated. Also I am getting SSID as null.

`info = SSID: , BSSID: 02:00:00:00:00:00, MAC: 02:00:00:00:00:00, Supplicant state: COMPLETED`

Permissions that I used:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

What is the best way to achieve above task?

Comment: I can see you declare `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in manifest, but is the permission granted? you must be granted this permission in order to get WiFi info.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel how do I check?

Comment: You must either request to user (yourself if you're debugging :) ) to grant your permission in runtime (or go manually to app info and turn on permission). I'll describe more in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An addition to @Shlomi's answer,

Here is the sample of getting permissions from user at runtime

> Perform a check before performing operation

```
if (!checkPermissions()) {
    // App does not have permissions, ask for permissions.
    requestPermissions()
} else {
    // App has permissions
    // Perform your operations here......
}
```

> Code to check and ask permissions

> Kotlin

```
/**
 * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
 */
private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
   
    val permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )
    return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun requestPermissions() {
    val shouldProvideRationale = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
            requireActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    )

    // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
    // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
    if (shouldProvideRationale) {
        Log.i(
                TAG,
                "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context."
        )
        Snackbar.make(
                binding.wifiConnectionFragment,
                "Location permission is needed for core functionality",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        )
            .setAction("OK") { // Request permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                        REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
                )
            }
            .show()
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission")
        // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
        // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
        // previously and checked "Never ask again".
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.isEmpty()) {

        } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission Granted
            // Perform your operations
        } else {
            // Permission denied.

            // Notify the user via a SnackBar that they have rejected a core permission for the
            // app, which makes the Activity useless. In a real app, core permissions would
            // typically be best requested during a welcome-screen flow.

            // Additionally, it is important to remember that a permission might have been
            // rejected without asking the user for permission (device policy or "Never ask
            // again" prompts). Therefore, a user interface affordance is typically implemented
            // when permissions are denied. Otherwise, your app could appear unresponsive to
            // touches or interactions which have required permissions.
            Snackbar.make(
                    binding.wifiConnectionFragment,
                    "Permission was denied, but is needed for core functionality.",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
            )
                .setAction(
                        "Settings",
                        View.OnClickListener { // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                            val intent = Intent()
                            intent.action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
                            val uri = Uri.fromParts(
                                    "package",
                                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null
                            )
                            intent.data = uri
                            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                            startActivity(intent)
                        })
                .show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have location permission in order to fetch WiFi AC details (see [Location Requirements for WiFi APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#location-telephony-bluetooth-wifi)).

Declaring `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in your manifest is not enough to get the WiFi info - the user must grant you that permission (either by requesting the permission from the user in runtime or manually turn on the permission by the user in app info).

Also, in Android 10, google added [enforcement that prevents you from getting the permission in the background](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#app-access-device-location), so keep in mind that only requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` only allows you fetching the WiFi AC details only if your app is in foreground.

To get the WiFi AC details in background, you must declare (and be granted with) `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` as well as the regular location permission.