# How to take marshmallow request permission for camera in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, camera

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this@MainActivity,
    String[]{ Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
    requestCameraPermissionID
```

I want to write this code in Kotlin but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost same in Kotlin as in Java.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
            requestCameraPermissionID
    )
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68437251/8641169) answer for more information.